# spring task:annotation-driven make young gc frequently

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I write a job to record something use @Scheduled,so I add task:annotation-driven  in applicationContext.xml.

ActivityCacheJob.java:

```
@Component
public class ActivityCacheJob {
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
  public void getActivityCacheStatus() {
    //dosomething
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

After deploying,I find young gc time rise from 3 to 15 each minute.

Then,I remove job but still add task:annotation-driven in applicationContext.xml.This problem still exists.

ActivityCacheJob.java:

```
//@Component
public class ActivityCacheJob {
//@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
  public void getActivityCacheStatus() {
    //dosomething
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

So,I remove task:annotation-driven, use xml,This problem does not exits.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="activityCacheJob" method="getActivityCacheStatus" cron="0 * * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

spring version:3.1.1.RELEASE

My question is why task:annotation-driven make young gc rise up?

Answer (score 1):

I update spring version from 3.1.1.RELEASE to 3.2.2.RELEASE.
This problem fixed.